# How to use Inclusions in SONAR 4.0?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am new to Sonar and need help in using Sonar's inclusion/Exclusion options. 
I have installed Sonar 4.0 and Sonar-Runner for running analysis on project.
Its a huge project with large number of classes. every time a new release comes, we hardly make changes to the 5% of the code.

This is the reason i need to include only the classes i have changed within one release.
For that i wanna use sonar's INCLUSION option. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the proper way to do it is to analyze the whole  code base each time and work in differential mode to focus on new issues, code coverage on new code, etc. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views